# Calibrating the SenseHat Raspberry Pi

Tags: coordinates, raspberry-pi2, compass

Currently I have been trying to set up a functioning compass on the raspberry pi using the SenseHat and I am using Raspbian Stretch, and I have run into an issue where the SenseHat is only picking up coordinates in the East to the South, essentially picking up coordinates in the 100s only. I have seen many things including on this site telling to install octave -y and then doing whatever. However, I don't know if it is because it is old and with the newest version of Raspbian it doesn't work anymore or something but I am running into error messages upon just trying to install. Does anyone have a way to recalibrate or just fix the coordinates the SenseHat is picking up? Getting something like this: E: /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with code 1. done. octave , with other issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: octave actually exists on the newest raspbian. There is however a specific case in which you must do a sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade then follow up with another update. Without the update after upgrade octave will not install. It is also better to use sudo apt install octave rather than sudo apt-get octave -y.